# Cannot import scikits-learn even though it seems to be installed

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scikits

Per the scikit-learn user guide, I installed scikit-learn using `pip install -U scikit-learn`.

So using `pip search scikit-learn`, I get this search result:

```
scikit-learn - A set of python modules for machine learning and data mining
INSTALLED: 0.12.1 (latest)
```

But when I go into Python and try to `import sklearn`, I get an `ImportError: No module named sklearn`. This really should have just worked.

I am using Enthought's free distribution of Python (2.7.3) on a Mac OS 10.6.8 with NumPy 1.6.1 and SciPy 0.10.1. Yes, I'm aware that EPD Free comes with scikit-learn but pip should have upgraded my version so that I can actually use scikit-learn.

Comment: Do you have more than one Python installed? The python you call `pip` with is the python that gets access to the module.

Comment: `python --version` from the command line and `import sys;` `sys.version` in the interactive enviroment.  The command line version should give you the version pip used.

Comment: @tcaswell Definitely using Python 2.7.3 which is provided with EPD Free. When I do a printenv, there does seem to be more than one Python in PATH, but the EPD Free version is earlier in PATH and should trump the other version.

Comment: find where ever pip installed the module, and make sure that path is in `sys.path`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks folks (see comment thread under the question)! It turns out that I have two versions of Python under my Mac's /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework directory tree: 2.7 (came with OSX) and 7.3 (installed by EPD Free).

It turns out `pip` put scikit-learn under 2.7 when I really wanted it under 7.3.

Changing directories to site-packages under the desired version of Python, and invoking `pip install -t . {package-name}` suffices to install package-name under the desired version of Python.

POSTLUDE (Feb 2021):
Looking back on this question from almost 9 years ago, I think I was running into a version of this XKCD comic.

[image: dependency management hell in python]

Nowadays, for dependency management of Python data engineering libraries like scikit, I'm happy with just using [conda](https://conda.io/en/latest/) and [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv).

Comment: could you elaborate on the command to be executed? It doesnt seem to work for me,and I think I have the same problem.

Answer (score 30):

Got same problem, @Alan gave correct solution but hard way.
Here are easy steps to resolve issue, as i am on mac osx, giving steps for same.

```
Ameys-Mac-mini:~ amey$ python --version
Python 2.7.2
Ameys-Mac-mini:~ amey$ cd /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/
Ameys-Mac-mini:site-packages amey$ brew install gcc
Ameys-Mac-mini:site-packages amey$ sudo pip install -t . numpy scipy scikit-learn
```

Comment: I get `must supply either home or prefix/exec-prefix -- not both`

Comment: @javadba, please follow this question you will get your solution . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41640935/pip-install-target-alfred-workflow-gives-an-error

Comment: If you want to install it for a specific python version, do `sudo python2.7 -m pip install -t . scikit-learn` or use environments.

Comment: I really wouldn't advise sudo pip installing anything. A year from now you'll kick yourself. Install without sudo to a virtualenv or a conda environment instead.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, my python extension has installed all in

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/
```

After I use the command given by the official site

```
pip install -U numpy scipy scikit-learn
```

the scikit-learn package was actually installed in my

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

So I copied all the packages in second to the first directory, then I can import the sklearn package.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference:

easy_install -U statsmodels

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I could figure out that python versions were different. I followed this [answer](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/PySpark-in-Zeppelin-Does-not-have-all-libraries/td-p/98286).

On Zeppelin page, go to the settings, Intepreter settings and change your python to python3.