# scikit-learn installed but does not work

Tags: python, macos, scikit-learn, pycharm

I am very new to Mac and I tried to install python and scikit-learn using this tutorials:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html
and 
http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/osx/

I am using Pycharm and when I look at the project interpreter, I can see the version of Python and also the packages that are installed in this version including numpy, scipy and scikit-learn. However, when I try to type "import sklearn", it does not work and it says "no module named sklearn"

has anyone had the same problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212987/cannot-import-scikits-learn-even-though-it-seems-to-be-installed - is this your issue?

Comment: I knew that I had several versions of python and I actually was using the right version. However, The problem was because of Pycharm. seems Pycharm has a preference option and it the default python version was set wrong there. So, I had to change that one too.