# Pip install --target=. Alfred-Workflow gives an error

Tags: python, macos, alfred

I am trying to install a python library on macOS following through [these instructions](https://github.com/deanishe/alfred-workflow#with-pip).

However I get an error every time I run this command : `pip install --target=. Alfred-Workflow`

And I always get this error for running it :

```
pip install --target=. Alfred-Workflow       
Collecting Alfred-Workflow
Installing collected packages: Alfred-Workflow
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 247, in move_wheel_files
    prefix=prefix,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/locations.py", line 153, in distutils_scheme
    i.finalize_options()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/install.py", line 264, in finalize_options
    "must supply either home or prefix/exec-prefix -- not both"
DistutilsOptionError: must supply either home or prefix/exec-prefix -- not both
```

I tried googling and searching for this but still can't figure it out. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Try [removing the equals sign `=`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-t) - `pip install -t . Alfred-Workflow`

Comment: Doesn't work. Gives a similar message : http://i.imgur.com/hu5q9qp.png

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DistutilsOptionError: must supply either home or prefix/exec-prefix -- not both](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257803/distutilsoptionerror-must-supply-either-home-or-prefix-exec-prefix-not-both)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257803/distutilsoptionerror-must-supply-either-home-or-prefix-exec-prefix-not-both) question answers that (I found it when googling for the last line of your error message).

First I also got the same error message as you did, but after doing this:

```
$ echo "[install]
prefix=" > ~/.pydistutils.cfg
```

It works:

```
$ pip install --target=. Alfred-Workflow
Collecting Alfred-Workflow
Installing collected packages: Alfred-Workflow
Successfully installed Alfred-Workflow-1.24
```

**Important note**: it breaks normal `pip install` commands, so you need to `rm ~/.pydistutils.cfg` afterward.

Comment: I did. In the question you linked, it says "If you create ~/.pydistutils.cfg file with "empty prefix" instruction it will fix this problem but it will break normal pip operations.". Is my pip broken now too?

Comment: oh yes, it does! Thanks for pointing out. I added a note to the answer

Comment: Is there a way to fix this issue without breaking normal pip install and having to rm ~/.pydistutils.cfg every time after running this command?

Comment: apparently not, at least according to the discussion at the question I linked. As far as I understand it's a homebrew issue, so you could reinstall python without homebrew, I would expect that this issue is fixed this way

Answer (score 5):

I have a similar error installing python modules using pip with -t(--target) option.

The pip log show the next message:

> Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-LvB_CW/xlrd/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-UNJizV-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --home=/tmp/tmphjBN23

and the next error:

> can't combine user with prefix, exec_prefix/home, or install_(plat)base

Reading about [alternate installation](https://docs.python.org/2/install/index.html#alternate-installation) on python docs I see the next info

> Note that the various alternate installation schemes are mutually exclusive: you can pass --user, or --home, or --prefix and --exec-prefix, or --install-base and --install-platbase, but you can’t mix from these groups.

So the command executed by pip has two mutually exclusive schemes **--user** and **--home** (i think it could be a bug on pip).

I use the **--system** option to avoid the error, eliminating the --user flag on the setup command.

> pip install -t path_to_dir module_name --system

I don't known the aditional implications of this usage, but i think it's better than modifing the config file that messed up with normal installations.

PD: I use ubuntu 15.10 with pip 1.5.6

Comment: Got it working after adding --system flag. Thank you!